# Executing Javascript from .Net (IE doesn't run in session 0)

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, vb.net, internet-explorer

I have a few Javascript libraries that do some useful transforms however, I needed run them from a .Net service in order to use the results for follow on calculations.  None of that is really important but the bottom line is I didn't want to re-write the libraries into .Net and I couldn't find a simple, ready-made solution that would work.

So what I did was have the service write out a HTML file with the data I need processed and then execute IE in the active session in order for the libraries to process the data.  The service sets up a local HTTP listener and the HTML file has an Ajax callback to send the results back to my service.  It works great in most cases.

The problem I'm seeing though is that when there is no active session the IE instances just hang.  The Javascript never executes and my service can't continue to process the data without these results.  IE is installed in Windows by default and I have some restrictions on software so I can't try other browsers and am kind of stuck with IE (or maybe Edge).

My question is, is there a reason IE doesn't execute Javascript in session 0?  I couldn't find any documentation about it but I'm assuming there is some restriction in place.  If that's the case is there a way to remove said restrictions?  Also, is there a way to debug what's happening if there is no active session such as increased IE logging.  The HTML/Javascript that is written to the file that gets executed is sound because it works in an active session without any issues.  It just doesn't work in session 0.

Comment: "Why software companies don't make UI programs intended for regular users to run in headless sessions" (which what you are asking) is a bit too broad for SO... SO is for concrete technical questions and not about business reasons behind technical decisions... (there are obviously tons of existing suggestion how to run headless browsers as well as how to run JS in .Net so be careful if you decide to re-purpose question that way)

Comment: It's totally a technical question.  I was just providing reasoning because people always ask.

Comment: The question I see in the post is "is there a reason IE doesn't execute Javascript in session 0" which is feels asking about business justification of not supporting headless mode for program that is designed for active user interaction. Do you for example make sure if your C# code runs on microwave oven or Ti-84 calculator? Why don't you - there maybe someone trying to use it that way :)

Comment: I'm not even sure why I bother with this site.